# Logic not firing correctly in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, logical-operators

**Edit:** I've solved the problem by changing the 2d array to a simple array and using arithmetic and logic to get coordinates, see below.

I have an algorithm that adds 50 to a two dimensional array when the coordinates have an odd-odd pairing (e.g. [1][1], [3][5], etc). The only problem is, it isn't working. According to the browser console it never fires. This is what it is:

```
if(((col & 1) & row) == 1) { y+= 50; }
```

A fuller example of my code is here:

```
//goes through the board's array and calls
//drawChecker to print each found piece
function drawPieces() {

    var row = 0;
    var col= 0;

    for(row = 0; row < 1; row++) {

        var y = row * 100;

        console.log("row " + row + " set x to " + x);
        var flag = (row & 1);

        for(col = 0; col < 8; col++) {

            var x = col*50;

            console.log("column " + col + " set y to " + y);

            console.log("y was " + y);
            if(((col & 1) & row) == 1) { y+= 50; }
            console.log("Now y is " + y);

            console.log("Done setting " + row + "," + col);

            console.log("Final coordinates are " + x + "," + y);
            drawChecker(x,y,square[row][col]);
        }
    }
}
```

The array was set up with the following code:

```
var square = new Array(4);
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) { square[i] = new Array(8); }
```

Comment: where should the result of the calculation go? to square?

Comment: You only have a single row `for(row = 0; row < 1; row++)`

Comment: It would be better to use `square.length` as limit in the outer `for` loop and `square[row].length` in the inner, instead of fixed values.

Comment: Nina: it's just supposed to fire off adding 50 to y. I'm not changing the contents of square[][], just where it will be placed when drawChecker() runs.I set it to only one row for the time being, but I can't even get that working.

Comment: on row 0 nothing happen, because it is not odd.

Answer (score 1):

You can not test the algorithms just on row `0`.

```js
function drawPieces() {
    square.forEach(function (a, i) {
        a.forEach(function (b, j) {
            if (i & j & 1) {
                square[i][j] = '#';
            }
        });
    });
}

var square = Array.apply(null, { length: 4 }).map(function () { return Array.apply(null, { length: 8 }).map(function () { return '.'; }); });
drawPieces();
document.write('<pre>'+square.map(function (a) { return a.join(''); }).join('\n')+'</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up switching my 2d array of 4x8 to a 1d array of 32 elements, and I changed the function to just this:

```
function drawPieces() {

    for(i = 0; i < 32; i++) {

        var value = square[i];
        var x = (i % 4) * 100; //i%4 gets its column, 0-3
        var y = Math.floor(i / 4) * 50;  //i / 4 gets the row 0-3

        if((i & 4) != 4) { x += 50; } //offset on even-numbered rows

        drawChecker(x,y,value);

        console.log(i + " has coordinates " + x + "," + y);
    }
}
```